# Is there a MySQL query that will only show the string searched for?

Tags: mysql, regex

I only want to return the file names of images from records satisfying the search. So something like:

```
SELECT [just the string in the regexp like $1 in Perl] FROM articles 
WHERE content REGEXP 'img src="([a-z0-9A-Z\.\-\\/]+)';
```

Is that even possible? I know REPLACE will single out words in a record, but can't find an equivalent.

Comment: MySQL just checks whether the field/value *matches* the regex, it doesn't support capture groups.

Comment: You'll have to use another language to parse the result and pull out the URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no builtin function that will return just the portion of the string that was matched.

MySQL `REGEXP` operator returns a boolean.

Normally, we'd pull the column back to the client, and do the required processing in the client.

To get this done in MySQL, you could write a custom function. Aside from writing a function to handle that simple regular expression in your example, such a function would be non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks, what I figured. Just didn't want to write a Perl routine to do this if I didn't have to.